# How to write PHP to Mysql page

Tags: php, html, database

Currently I just done HTML and I trying writing PHP Script on connection Mysql, But all web site on google is confuse, because now I need specify write connection by used PHP Only,

Please could you help explain step by step on code from HTML to PHP and write PHP to MySql, Thank you very much.

Comment: your flow is strange. Mysql page? You have a php page that will ask something to the db and the print some html (your page)

Comment: google for php and mysql tutorials and when you have a specified problem, we will help you

Comment: There are literally hundreds of tutorials on basic PHP and MySQL. StackOverflow is not the place for you yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is many docs about this, but you can start from here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

And here is the example code, what i suggest you:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```